# What's the best way to store Color arrays in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a component that allows me to change the camera background color along a gradient of Colors:

[image]

I was thinking it would be nice to be able to store these arrays of Colors separately from the component (for example, I might want swap the colors on the fly, and having some premade Color arrays would facilitate this). I was wondering if there were any ideal ways to store objects like arrays of Colors.

My favorite solution so far would be to create prefabs that stored the arrays of Colors, and having the `GradientController` read from those, since it would be easy to swap prefabs on the fly. I also thought about storing the colors as hex codes in text files, and reading from them. Is there any approach that would be better than those?

Comment: ScriptableObjects would be nice.

Comment: As he mentioned, use ScriptableObject and save it as asset, and load asset using bundle or attach it to prefab. it would be the best solution I guess

Comment: Not directly an answer to your question, but may I suggest using the built-in [gradient](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html) type which has its own custom inspector editor?

Comment: Did not know about ScriptableObjects, or that Gradients had their own inspection editor!